# Typescript wrapper function for readonly useState

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I want to make a wrapper funtion useStateRO that will mark all properties as readonly, so that state could be changed only using setState, but can't make a right type for return value.

[CodeSandBox example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-j2xgi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends (infer R)[]
  ? DeepReadonlyArray<R>
  : T extends Function
  ? T
  : T extends object
  ? DeepReadonlyObject<T>
  : T;

function useStateRO<T>(
  props: T
): [DeepReadonly<T>, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>] {
  return useState<DeepReadonly<T>>(props); // fix needed
}

interface IX {
  x: number;
}

function App() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState<IX>({ x: 1 });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTest({ x: 2 });
  }, []);
  console.log(test.x);
  test.x = 5; // should be error

  return <div>Hi</div>;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2):

As always, finding solution myself after making sandbox and having formulated question :/

```
function useStateRO<T>(props: T): [DeepReadonly<T>, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>] {
  return useState(props) as [DeepReadonly<T>, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>]
}
```